# How to crack Winrar password without any software

Tags: passwords, winrar, password-recovery

Anybody know how to crack the Winrar password without using any software. I forgot my password which is having more than 7 characters and have special symbols. So if I use any of the software it will take more time to get the password?

Comment: If there was a way to easily retrieve a password there would be no sense in setting it.

Comment: "forgot". yeah. right. How do you think it is possible without any software, apart from use a pen and paper to write down all the passwords you can remember and try them.

Comment: its just because i need thar much security for that file and i kept my password with me.. but unfortunately i lost it.. and thats y i posted here..  otherwise why  should i ask here :(.. and why you people are thinking like this.. its soo sad

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes. It's a new user, should we come off as *this* unhelpful? There's just one answer: "It's not possible".

Comment: Wait, since when is that "Windows". @Sathya — are you sure he meant Windows? He's talking about having security for a file. Doesn't sound like a Windows issue, but a protected RAR archive.

Comment: *ulp* I goofed up. Need to tweak the regex on my editor @slhck

Comment: @raki, please specify clearly what you want. Is it "your Windows password", or a password for some archive, or what?

Comment: @Linker3000    why did u editted my question?? i never want to crack windows password :-X  my qstn was regarding WINRAR ... and why you people behaving like this ? 
I dosent know much more about all these and thats why people like me are postin in such sites and you people are laughing oon our ignorance.. its too shame .. just think for a moment what you people are doing and then respond.. please

Comment: @ glglgl .. thanks for understanding me... am talking about retreving the password for a rar archive file and some guys editted my question

Comment: It wasn't @Linker3000, It was me. It was a mistake by me which resulted in WinRar -> Windows substitution, have reverted my edit.

Comment: Do you know any of the characters and their positions in the password? This can cut down on processing time for software.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know how cryptographically secure WinRAR is.

A really secure algorithm can only be cracked by brute force.

OTOH, I have read some time that zip files only have weak protection and are easy to crack. (Not sure about that.)

So you won't be able to cope without a program, which will need about 70 ^ 7 = 8E12 (8  trillion) tries, if you include letters, digits and special characters.

I am sure that there are programs you can give a hint which places in the password are known (if you can remember some of them) - that wil dramatically reduce the time.

---

EDIT: As you have *more* than 7 characters, it is even much more than 8E12, alas.